# Prevent double click on OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener, double-click

I tried to prevent the user from clicking on my button twice. I tried to use `setEnabled` on my script but nothing happens! My problems are, I tried to do this in `setOnClickListener`.

Can someone please help me to find a solution to prevent clicking while everything is being uploaded to the server?

```
newPostBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // I want to set my button to enabled false here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `setOnAction`?

```
newPostBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
    (your logic goes here)

    newPostBtn.setEnabled(false);
}) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

1) make an instance variable:

```
 private int buttonClicks;
```

2) instantiate your variable in onCreate

```
 buttonClicks = 0;
```

3) set if() statement in onClickListener

```
newPostBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            if (buttonClicks == 1){
               buttonClicks = 0;
               //do nothing
               } else {

                //run code
                }
                   buttonClicks++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are the three ways to fix this:

Disable the button with `setEnabled(false)` until it is safe for the user to click it again.

[Above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52107011/2196176) given solution is also a way to fix it.

Another solution is

```
private long lastClickTime = 0;

View.OnClickListener buttonHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // preventing double, using threshold of 1000 ms
        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastClickTime < 1000){
            return;
        }

        lastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes next screens/actions takes time to be executed and frequent taps or clicks on view performs that next screen/action multiple times. I resolved this issue by counting time between two clicks. Please find code example below:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // mis-clicking prevention, using threshold of 1000 ms
        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000){
            return;
        }
        mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

        // do your action here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try **setClickable**

In Android, a widget that is not clickable will not respond to click events

> view.setClickable(false);

```
newPostBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setClickable(false);

// I want to set my button to enabled false here
}}
```